# Word for an action/event that contributes to a person's notoriety?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Just as achievements can contribute to a person's fame, is there an equivalent word for an action or event that contributes to a person's notoriety? Phrases that come to mind are 'bad deed' or 'cruel act', but no words come to mind.

Comment: Malfeasance, misdeed, devilry, malefaction, villainy, mischief, malpractice..

Answer (score 1):

Ignominy ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignominy))

> disgraceful or dishonorable conduct, quality, or action

Infamy ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infamy))

> an extreme and publicly known criminal or evil act

Scandal ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scandal))

> a circumstance or action that offends propriety or established moral conceptions or disgraces those associated with it

Atrocity ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atrocity))

> a shockingly bad or atrocious act, object, or situation the atrocities of war